# How to replace a video on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I need to make a small correction in a video I uploaded to YouTube. Googling shows that this is not possible. However, I remember seeing it done before. I posted a comment on a video saying that a certain part of the video was missing. I got a reply back that it was fixed, and when I went to see the video again, it was changed. How was this done?

Comment: You can always remove an existing video and upload an edited version, but it sounds like you want to change a video's content in place. This may be an advanced privilege only given to YouTube Partners.

Comment: Yes, I want to change it without losing the view count and original address.

Comment: You can do this on Vimeo, but not YouTube. ie. You can completely replace a video with a different video in the original's place and retain all comments and viewcounts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Videos can not be replaced, but they can be edited.

Quote from YouTube Help ([Replace or delete your video](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/55770)):

> You can’t replace a video since any new video uploads will get a new URL, but you can make changes to the existing video.

Answer (score 8):

It should't be possible and I hope it's not. The reason is simple: Let's say you are uploading one really interesting video that goes viral with few millions views and then you are changing it to something completely boring. Wouldn't it be a little bit confusing for the new viewers on why exactly this video got so many views?

I think you can make few tweaks to the video from what YouTube offers you and maybe the [editor](http://www.youtube.com/editor) could help, but I'm not a YouTuber to know anything more.

Comment: A fair point, but let's also say you uploaded a video ages ago before Youtube could handle HD video.  I have a video with several thousand hits that I can't upgrade to HD because of this.

Comment: @MattDell true... that's the only valid reason. Who knows, maybe they will implement a technology that will automate somehow the verification.

Comment: I would think they could use the same technology they use to verify content isn't copyrighted to make sure the differences in your video are minimal/just being upgraded to HD. I hope at least that much can happen one day, though I sometimes need to make other small changes to my videos.

Comment: Why couldn't they introduce the concept of version history? Then watchers could decide they want to view originals, or view most recent updates.

Comment: Lipis> `true... that's the only valid reason.` Really? The *only* valid reason? You can't stretch your brain to think of even a single other valid reason? Say for example correcting an error like a typo or misspoken word or something without having to re-upload the whole video over again and losing all of the comments, views, etc. on it? (There are other valid reasons, that's just the most obvious and *extremely* common one that people wish they could do this.)

Comment: @Lipis> `Who knows, maybe they will implement a technology that will automate somehow the verification` They already have a long time ago, they just don't let most people do it. There have been a couple of occasions where YouTube sneakily replaced its own videos or other big companies (iirc Disney) were allowed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, probably the issue is not that YouTube would or would not allow video replacement but it’s the original content that can't be altered. By allowing such ability, it would contaminate the authenticity of original content.