# How to blur a section in a video that is already uploaded?

Tags: youtube

I realized I opened a Chrome tab that I don't want shown in the video. The video already had 500 views and thumbs up, etc. I don't want to take it down just to re-upload it.

Is there a way using YouTube effects to blur parts of a video, or cut part of it out?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/how-to-replace-a-video-on-youtube